# Type '(props: Props, ref: ForwardedRef<HTMLElement>) => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForwardRefRenderFunction'

Tags: typescript

Argument of type '(props: Props, ref: ForwardedRef) => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLButtonElement, Props>'.

I tried everything and it does not work. Please help lol

```
const DatePicker = forwardRef((props:any, ref:any) => {
```

export default DatePicker

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I did now. Hope it helps.